# Is Python 3.5's grammar LL(1)?

Tags: python, parsing, compiler-construction, grammar

I saw http://matt.might.net/teaching/compilers/spring-2015/ saying Python 3.4 is LL(1)

Is Python 3.5's grammar still LL(1) so one can write a recursive descent parser?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. This is a deliberate language feature, and not just something that happened to be the case. [PEP 3099](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3099/) explicitly *rejected* any changes to this for the Python 2 -> 3 transition (a notably bigger transition than any 3.x -> 3.y will be):

> - The parser won't be more complex than LL(1).
>
>   Simple is better than complex. This idea extends to the parser. Restricting Python's grammar to an LL(1) parser is a blessing, not a
>     curse. It puts us in handcuffs that prevent us from going overboard
>     and ending up with funky grammar rules like some other dynamic
>     languages that will go unnamed, such as Perl.

Comment: CPython 3.9 [introduced a PEG parser](https://peps.python.org/pep-0617/) which 'lift[s] the LL(1) restriction on the current Python grammar' and also that PEP says it 'allow[s] the elimination of multiple “hacks” that exist in the current grammar to circumvent the LL(1)-limitation', so I think this answer isn't quite true in practice either.

Comment: Subjectively, the new PEG grammar is quite awful though, and PEG as the standard is infectious and forces all Python implementations to use it. The PEP itself explicitly states that the new maintainers did not pick any of the better approaches because they did not understand parsing theory:

"We did not seriously consider alternative ways to implement the new parser, but [...] Other variants of LR were not considered, nor was LL (e.g. ANTLR). PEG was selected because it was easy to understand given a basic understanding of recursive-descent parsing."