# Eliminate indirect First-First conflicts in LL 1 grammar

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar, parser-generator

I am trying to write a LL(1) parser generator and I am running into a issue with grammars which I know to be LL(1) but I cannot factor them properly.

For example consider the grammar:

```
S -> As Ao
As -> a As
As -> Ɛ
Ao -> a
Ao -> Ɛ
```

Now this grammar has a first-follow conflict in `As` so I perform Ɛ elimination and have:

```
S -> As Ao
S -> Ao
As -> a As
As -> a
Ao -> a
Ao -> Ɛ
```

Which has a first-first conflicts in `S` and `As`. Resolving the conflict in `As` produces:

```
S -> As Ao
S -> Ao
As -> a As'
As' -> As
As' -> Ɛ 
Ao -> a
Ao -> Ɛ
```

Which has a first-follow conflict in `As'` which when eliminated simply cycles. Further, the conflict in `S` cannot be solved via left factorization

I believe the issue is that `As Ao == As` if I knew how to prove this I believe the issue would go away as the initial grammar could be transformed to:

```
S -> As
As -> a As
As -> Ɛ
```

Is there standard techniques for resolving such conflicts?

edit:
I realize the grammar above is ambiguous. The grammar I am really interested in parsing is:

```
S -> a As Ao
As -> , a AS
As -> Ɛ
Ao -> ,
Ao -> Ɛ
```

I.e. a comma separated list of `a` with an optional trailing comma.

Answer (score 1):

The original grammar is ambiguous, so no deterministic parser can be produced.

Of course, you can eliminate the ambiguities easily enough, since the language is just "zero or more `a`s":

```
S  ⇒ As
As ⇒ a As
As ⇒ Ɛ
```

But presumably the question is a simplification of some more complicated grammar in which `Ao` is not the same as `a`, but in which `FIRST(As)` and `FIRST(Ao)` have some common element.

In general, it is difficult to write LL(1) grammars for such languages, and it is indeed possible that such a grammar does not exist for the language. In order to answer the question in more detail, it would be necessary to understand what is meant by the claim that the grammar is known to be LL(1).

Comment: I am tying to generate a parser generator that can consume to the grammar of python.  According to their documentation it is LL(1).   Your guess that my grammar is a simplification is correct.  The thing I am having issues with is:
`S -> NUMBER (, NUMBER)* [,]` which is not ambiguous.

Comment: @altf4: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53597413/1566221

Comment: I think it might be.  I was using a different transformation from EBNF to BNF.